# Validate user required fields

Tags: 7, users

I'm using Drupal 7 and I have some PHP pages that depends on my Drupal site.
In the PHP page, I tried to add a user programmatically in order the check the exception:

```
try {
  $new_user = array(
    'name' => 'user'
  );
  user_save('', $new_user);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I didn't give all the required field, like email and some custom fields that I set in *Home » Administration » Configuration » People » Account settings*, but Drupal still added this user.

I need the following:

1. Get all user field(s) and check if they are required or not
2. Get error on exception when I'm trying to add user without required fields

How should I do that?

Comment: Drupal added the user because you told it to. The validation is tied to form submission, an unfortunate design choice. There's a function to submit forms in code though, which is possibly a place to start for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't create user this way, as it's bypassing all the controls made by drupal.

You can retrieve registration form this way:

```
drupal_get_form('user_register_form');
```

And print it like this:

```
print(drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_register_form')));
```

Comment: In that case I have no choice. Doesn't Drupal has validation methods?

Comment: Maybe you can try this ? https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_form_submit/7
This will perform all the validation methods on the form.